# Error: Selected item of spinner is not coverting to string

Tags: java, android, string, spinner

I am trying to convert the selected item from a spinner to string format so I can save it in a database.  I have the code below in use for it at the moment, however, in my database the selected item is coming up as android.widget.TextView@5372bab4

Java code:

```
sCauseFactor = causeFactor.getSelectedView().toString();
```

Does anybody know the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getSelectedItem()` method to get the selected item in the spinner.

```
causeFactor.getSelectedItem().tostring()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much.  Feel like saying DUUUH, haha, had the answer in the question.

Comment: I can in another 4 minutes.